# Check a customer list for purchases

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a patient list that includes the patient number, the date of hospital entry, the day of visit and the type of care that they required during the visit, if any. Some of them only stayed for a sigle day and therefore have a single entry, while most of them have multiple entries for each day they stayed in the hospital. Is there a way to check whether each patient received a specific type of care during their whole stay? I have tried with an IF function geting the values from the respective columns but i only got as fas as getting the type of care that they had on their first day without showing what happened on the other days: `=IF('[@date_of_visit]'='[@date_of_entry]';'[@Care];'blank')`
and whether they received care on each day: `=IF([@Care]="Care_1";"YES";IF([@Care]="Care_2";"YES";IF([@Care]="Care_3";"YES";IF([@Care]="Care_4";"YES";IF([@Care]="No_Care";"No";IF([@Care]="N.A.";"N.A.";"N.A."))))))`

I would like to have a single cell for each patient describing whether there was care given to them during the visit or not and my problem lies in the fact that most patients were visited over many days and hence have multiple entries.

Edit: Updated 1st formula for accuracy

Comment: the `IF` statement might work but you might just do =isblank([@Care]) and then use conditional formatting for all of the FALSE values.

Comment: Without data sample it's only a guess but sounds like a COUNTIFS case...

Comment: If you're looking to see if a given patient had a given CPT code, I would first take the list of patients, remove duplicates. Then using that CPT (or however you identify 'care') and countifs based on the patient identifier AND the care identifier, this will tell you how many times they had that care. You can have several columns for different codes in order to check for multiple.

Comment: The COUNTIFS solution is probably correct. I ended up using a pivot table to do it though as i had to add more columns with more patient data that needed summaries. I simply added a column that checks if the visit date is the same as the entry date and the pivot table can filter through them.